# getting hexdata back from binary format in python

Tags: python, hex, binary-data

I'm trying to convert hexdata into binary and then back to hex. I'm getting hexdata but as byte object

```
    hexdata='91278c4bfb3cbb95ffddc668d995bfe0'
    b=binascii.a2b_hex(hexdata)
    print (b)
    b"\x91'\x8cK\xfb<\xbb\x95\xff\xdd\xc6h\xd9\x95\xbf\xe0"
    binascii.b2a_hex(b)
    b'91278c4bfb3cbb95ffddc668d995bfe0'
```

I'm expecting this to come as simple string (as my input i.e., `hexstring`) that I can use in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just decode the bytestring as ASCII:

```
binascii.b2a_hex(b).decode('ASCII')
```

as hex digits are limited to the characters 0-9 and a-f.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the following code:

```
hexa = '91278c4bfb3cbb95ffddc668d995bfe0'
binary = bin(int(hexa, 16))[2:]
print binary
hexa_dec = hex(int(binary, 2))[2:]
print hexa_dec
```

Comment: Dead Sir, you have formed a habit of answering questions with code only and no explaining text. Please write a few lines about the code you give as answers.